# Running a .Net language program in a browser

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I would like to try out a demo (more like a proof of concept), which involves running a .Net language in a browser.

I am talking about a kind of IDE that allows you to do the following:

1. Step through code (i.e. debug) and inspect variables
2. Run the application

All through a web browser interface

Is there any software out there that already does that?

If no, can someone share some ideas on how to get started in building such a proof of concept demo - i.e. what are the main steps required to put a "Hello world" example together?

Comment: Should .net run clientside or server side? Clientside there is Silverlight, but I wouldn't call it a browser application anymore. And serverside one can sandbox an AppDomain and run the code the user sends.

Comment: Code should run server side. I was thinking of the solution yo proposed, but I was not sure how to 'tie' the frontend and backend together - any ideas on this (i.e. specifically, what messages to send between the f/e and backend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty interesting implementation here (stumbled upon it earlier looking for something similar):

http://www.coderun.com/

Online IDE for C#, JavaScript, and PHP.

Comment: wow, pretty impressive - but I want to run the code on my own server. coderun does not seem to be open source - or did I miss that part?

Comment: No, I don't believe it is open source. I didn't realize that was one of your requirements.